# Format of Moderator elections page confusing

Tags: support, status-completed, election

I find the format of the [moderator elections page](https://gis.stackexchange.com/election) confusing. I had to read it several times before it was clear to me that Mapperz' post was actually a response and not the author of the elections announcement:

[image]

Everywhere else in Stack Exchange the opening question/post is followed by a signature block and some other elements before the responses are listed. Please don't break the usual pattern without good reason (and I don't see one here. Maybe I'm missing something).

[image]

*((update: edited pics to make it apparent they are screenshots))*

Comment: I agree with Matt.  Also, are we able to nominate other users through that page?

Answer (score 1):

We have added a header to the top counting the number of Candidates across all election tabs.  We appreciate feedback and will continue to make changes that help with usability.

Comment: Thanks, @Geoff.  However, I don't see any change whatsoever on the page referenced by @Matt.  Exactly what page are you referring to?

Comment: @Whu it will be deployed tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we've had 12+ elections and this is the first I've ever heard of this. There is a tab block and a HR there, so to me it's pretty clear..

I guess we could add

## 12 Candidates

where we have

## 3 Answers

above, if that helps...

Comment: There are graphical differences among the sites, Jeff. A close look does suggest some inconsistencies here. For instance, messages are usually terminated by the usual panel of tags, links, badges. The nominations page has no such termini: it segues directly into the first self-nomination, reading as if the nomination were an integral part of the message itself. To someone who did not see the original message before nominations were entered, the change in author is not apparent. *The user should get the benefit of the doubt in usability questions,* not the designer.

Comment: @whu but this is the only time I've ever heard this feedback.. in 10+ elections!

Comment: I appreciate that information; it makes one reconsider.  But here as well as in general, when a user--especially a distinguished one like a mod--has a problem interpreting something, *it's the designer's responsibility to pay attention,* not to dismiss it.  On this site the users use maps and graphics to communicate and through this experience are aware of the pitfalls: map readers (and, *mutatis mutandis,* Web page readers) *create* meaning by using *your* graphical cues.  When they start creating unintended interpretations, *it's not your fault,* but you still ought to do something!